# Switch vs SelectMany + TakeUntil

Tags: system.reactive

I'm writing an operator that effectively does the same as Switch plus some other stuff. I always understood Switch to effectively be a neat wrapper around SelectMany combined with TakeUntil. However whilst implementing my new extension I've noticed something different about the order of creation/disposal of inner sequences. I'm wondering how I can replicate the order Switch works in since it seems likely we'd always want to dispose the existing inner before creating a new one.

I've written 2 tests to illustrate what I mean.

StandardSwitch will give the following output: 
Disposing Inner followed by Creating New Inner

HandCrankedSwitch will give: 
Creating New Inner,
Disposing Inner

See example code below:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void StandardSwitch()
    {
        var outer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("New Outer Value is {0}", x));

        var wait = new CountdownEvent(8);

        outer
            .Select(CreateInner)
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Subscriber Got {0}", x);
                wait.Signal();
            });

        wait.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

[TestMethod]
    public void HandCrankedSwitch()
    {
        var outer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("New Outer Value is {0}", x));

        var wait = new CountdownEvent(8);

        outer.Publish(x => x.Select(CreateInner).SelectMany(xs => xs.TakeUntil(x)))
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Subscriber Got {0}", x);
                wait.Signal();
            });

        wait.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
internal IObservable<long> CreateInner(long notUsed)
    {
        return Observable.Create<long>(obs =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating New Inner");

            var compDis = new CompositeDisposable {Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Disposing Inner"))};

            var dis = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4))
                .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("New Inner Value is {0}", x))
                .Subscribe(obs);

            compDis.Add(dis);

            return compDis;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not a 100% sure, but I think Select(xs => xs.TakeUntil(x)).Concat() simulates Switch() closer than SelectMany(cs => xs.TakeUntil(x)). The latter is the same as Select(xs => xs.TakeUntil(x)).Merge().

Comment: Yes interestingly it works with Concat. I've looked at the Rx Sourcecode and actually Concat just calls Merge but with an additional parameter to limit concurrency. I'm trying to think if this can have any potentially unexpected side effects... Looking at the source code for switch which is much more involved it uses a SerialDisposable for the inner sequence and resets this before subscribing to the new Inner hence the order of events.